# How to calculate the number of atoms of each element in Mg(NO3)2?

Tags: atoms, mole

I'm working on chemistry and I'm not quite sure how to solve this question? I haven't worked with moles before and whenever I try to figure out how to do these types of question I only end up confusing myself more.

> How many Mg atoms are in 5.7892 mol of $\ce{Mg(NO3)2}$?
>
> How many N atoms does the sample contain?
>
> How many O atoms does the sample contain?

I haven't any clue how to do this so a walkthrough on how to solve these types of problem would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$\ce{Mg(NO3)2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_nitrate) has (Figure 1):

- One $\ce{Mg}$ atom
- Two $\ce{NO3}$ groups, which are composed of:

  - One $\ce{N}$ atom
  - Three $\ce{O}$ atoms

[image: Magnesium nitrate]

**Figure 1**: we have one $\ce{Mg}$, two $\ce{N}$ ($2 \times 1$) and six $\ce{O}$ ($2 \times 3$) in $\ce{Mg(NO3)2}$.

Now all you need is to know that [1 mole equals $6.022\,140\,76\times 10^{23} \approx 6.022 \times 10^{23}$ particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant).
Just multiply:

> How many Mg atoms are in 5.7892 mol of $\ce{Mg(NO3)2}$?

$$1 \times 5.7892 \text{ mol $\ce{Mg}$} = 1 \times 5.7892 \times 6.022 \times 10^{23} \text{ atoms $\ce{Mg}$} \\= 3.48625624 \times 10^{25} \text{ atoms $\ce{Mg}$}$$

And so on.

Comment: Your equation is not correct since there are different dimensions on both sides of the equal sign (on the left amount of substance in mol, on the right a dimensionless number). It would be better if you use the Avogadro constant instead of the Avogadro number four your calculation.